# Example of chunked transfer encoding

Tags: apache, http, encoding, http-headers

I was about to test `chunked` transfer encoding with the following simple Perl script:

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n";
print "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n\n";
print "11\n\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
print "11\n\n";
print "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
print "\n\n";
```

But I experience a browser error

`Error 321 (net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING): Unknown error.`

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: It should be `\r\n` instead of `\n\n` (example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last (zero-sized) chunk is missing.